# Is it possible to perform inverse kinematics using MoveIt! plugin without defining dynamic parameters at urdf file?

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given that (in theory) kinematics (forward o inverse) doesn't care about dynamic parameters such as mass or inertial matrix /Ixx, Izxy, etc.( related to links and so on. Can I perform inverse kinematics using move it! plugin in Rviz without defining dynamic parameters in the URDF file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251695/is-it-possible-to-perform-inverse-kinematics-using-moveit!-plugin-without-defining-dynamic-parameters-at-urdf-file?/) by [protonauta](https://answers.ros.org/users/29007/protonauta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The URDF format doesn't require the dynamic parameters to be specified ([see here](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link)).  If you already have a moveit_config package created with the moveit setup assistant from the URDF then you can run the "move_group.launch" file there which provides a number of services.  One such service is the "/compute_ik" which returns a joint solution for your robot.

---

Originally posted by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) with karma: 486 on 2017-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0